# Addition doesn't work after copying a numpy array in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to copy a numpy array and change the value of the copied array.

When I create the *x* array using *np.array*, the addition doesn't work and it prints 2.00.

```
import numpy as np
import copy

x = np.array([2,3,4])
inc= np.array([0.2,0.3,0.4])
    
x_copy = copy.copy(x)
x_copy[0] = x_copy[0] + inc[0]

print("x_copy %.2f" % x_copy[0])
```

But when I create *x* without *np.array*, it works and it prints 2.20.

```
import numpy as np
import copy

x = [2,3,4]       
inc= np.array([0.2,0.3,0.4])    

x_copy = copy.copy(x)
x_copy[0] = x_copy[0] + inc[0]

print("x_copy %.2f" % x_copy[0])
```

I also tried to copy *x* using *x.copy()*, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: That is because you are mixing array types. `x` stores integers not floats, so elements of `inc` are probably cast to integers before the addition occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

either

```
x =np.array([2.0,3.0,4.0])
```

or

```
x = np.array([2,3,4])
x = x.astype(float)
```

Comment: To avoid changing the content manually or having two lines, I'd go with `np.array([2, 3, 4], dtype=float)`.